# Docker: Ubuntu base image send Email using mail & mailx

Tags: docker, email, ubuntu, mailx

I'm trying to send mail using **Mail & Mailx from my AKS container**. I am using Ubuntu as a base image and have installed mailutils.

using the below command

```
RUN apt-get install -y mailutils
```

and tried the below command

```
echo "This is message body" | mail -s "This is Subject" someone@example.com
```

and it is throwing an error

> Dead Letter not found

My SMTP configuration is

```
    mailhost: mailhost.demo.com
    port: 25 
    auth:  
    username:  
    password:
```

however I have not configured/added anything in the docker file.

What should I do in the docker file so that I can send the email using Mail & Mailx?

Comment: What is your command to start the container (`docker run ...`) and where is the SMTP config file mounted into the container?

Comment: I don't have any SMTP config file as I don't know what is that.